# Use an id value to perform element-wise calculations on two data frames

Tags: r

I'm doing element-wise calculations on two data frames, but only where the same id exists in both sets of data.

The current method I'm using is to subset both data frames where the same ids exist, then sort the data by id, then do the calculation:

```
## Example data
id <- c('a','b','c','d','e')
v1 <- c(10, 20, 30,20,40)
v2 <- c(20,30,20,20,40)
df1 <- data.frame(id, v1, v2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

id <- c('a','c','d','b','f')
v1 <- c(20,60,30,10,20)
v2 <- c(60,20,50,10,20)
df2 <- data.frame(id, v1, v2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

## subset both data frames by ids that exist in both
df1_subset <- df[df1$id %in% df2$id,]
df2_subset <- df2[df2$id %in% df1$id,]
id <- df1_subset$id  

## arrange by id value
library(dplyr)
df1_sorted <- df1_subset %>% arrange(id)
df2_sorted <- df2_subset %>% arrange(id)

## find the difference between each value
df_result <- cbind(id, df2_sorted[,2:3] - df1_sorted[,2:3])
```

Is there a 'better' way of doing this calculation where the data doesn't need 
to be subset and sorted, and uses the id value directly to validate/ensure the calculation is being performed on the correct row & column of data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2, by="id") %>%
      mutate(v1=v1.y-v1.x, v2=v2.y-v2.x) %>% 
      select(id, v1, v2)
#  id  v1  v2
#1  a  10  40
#2  b -10 -20
#3  c  30   0
#4  d  10  30
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `merge` and then a single `transform` to do what you need:

```
#merge will find the common ids between the dataframes
a <- merge(df1,df2, by='id')
#transform will add the two columns you need (subtracting one from the other)
a <- transform(a, v1 = v1.y - v1.x, v2 = v2.y - v2.x)
```

Output:

```
> a
  id v1.x v2.x v1.y v2.y  v1  v2
1  a   10   20   20   60  10  40
2  b   20   30   10   10 -10 -20
3  c   30   20   60   20  30   0
4  d   20   20   30   50  10  30
```

Which is the same as your `df_result`

```
> df_result
  id  v1  v2
1  a  10  40
2  b -10 -20
3  c  30   0
4  d  10  30
```

Comment: nice!  `transform()` is a cleaner answer than mine

Comment: I had actually considered a `merge` based solution but wasn't so keen on processing/transforming the output. But it seems like the most appropriate method here so I'll go for it.

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you can easily join these DFs on id with `merge()` (In R base) :

```
df_merged = merge(df1,df2, by='id')
```

which gives you the following new column names:

```
names(df_merged)
# [1] "id"   "v1.x" "v2.x" "v1.y" "v2.y"
```

because `merge()` by default adds suffixes to colliding column names.

Then consider this combination to get your result ...

```
df_result = with(df_merged, data.frame(id, result1 = v1.x - v1.y, result2 = v2.x-v2.y)))
```

`with()` adds readability.   There are many many ways to do this.   Lots of nice libraries like `plyr`and `sqldf` to make it easy.   I look forward to seeing a more R-er way in the answers.